# ORMLite + MySQL: how to find one matching record?

Tags: java, mysql, ormlite

I have a java class named "Article" that uses ORMLite for connection/communication with MySQL database. My insertion works, but I have a question retrieving only one Article (corresponding to a row in the mysql database table) given an "id" (auto incremented in mysql database table).

It seems that I have to use a List variable to hold the query result:

```
Dao<Article,String> articleDAO = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Article.class);
List<Article> article = articleDAO.queryForEq("id", id); /* is there a method to find only one matching record and returns an Article type ? */
```

I wish to do something like this:

```
Article article = articleDAO.queryOne("id", id);
```

Comment: You can do `Article a = articleDAO.queryForId("1");` per example.

Comment: thanks ZouZou. I am just going to try that approach.

Comment: It should work, I just tested it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Youse the query `List<Article> article = articleDAO.queryForEq("id", id);` and than do somethink like that:

```
if (article != null && article.size() !=0){
  return article.get(0)
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've just read the API of ORMLite and found that **queryForId(id)** could work for me. I will try it out and will report back.

Answer (score 0):

> Article article = articleDAO.queryOne("id", id);

Uh, have you read any of the [online docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite.html)?  The `dao.queryForId(id)` is what is referenced all over the place.  It is designed to return the value that matches the unique id of a row the same way that `dao.update(...)` and `dao.refresh(...)` work to change and read that row from the database.

Also, there is a [`dao.queryForFirst(preparedQuery)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/BaseDaoImpl.html#queryForFirst%28com.j256.ormlite.stmt.PreparedQuery%29) which gets the first result from a query.